# Что есть вооружение?

Tags: значение-слов

По идее, ответ лежит на поверхности: вооружение - запас оружия. Но при этом, например, в обсуждении кораблей, которые плавают/ходят, есть замечание, что корабль - это парусник с парусным вооружением фрегата. Но паруса никак не отнести к оружию. А еще часто говорят в переносном смысле "вооружиться знаниями" или каким-то предметом.
Так что же такое все-таки вооружение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По Ожегову, вооружение

1-Снабжение средствами для ведения боя: оружие, техника.Идёт вооружение армии.

2.Совокупность средств для ведения войны.Новые виды вооружения.

3(спец.) Совокупность принадлежностей какого-нибудь устройства.Парусное вооружение судна.

Answer (score 1):

ОРУЖИЕ. Общеслав. Суф. производное от orǫzь "кол, палка" (ср. в др.-рус. яз. оружь — тж.), того же корня, что рог, болг. ръгам "прокалываю".
Яндекс.Словари › Этимологический словарь. — 2004